# How to get selected text from the window of any Ubuntu program?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a library that allows a form to respond to keystrokes. I need that, in my key combination, the selected text from the browser, text editors and all other windows of the operating system where the text can be selected with the mouse is copied into the variable. Tell me how to cling to the selected text? Maybe there is also a special library for this?

Comment: Monitor the clipboard for new string objects?

Comment: I want get selected text from any window to string variable, using my own keystroke. I have already created key listener for this operation, but don't know how to get text.